# Migrate SSIS packages from SQL 2005 windows 2003 to SQL 2022 windows 2022?

Tags: sql-server

is it possible to migrate / copy SSIS packages from SQL 2005 to SQL 2022.

All of our SSIS packages are in file system .dtsx file. We have project file which was designed in visual studio 2005. All are legacy and we are planning to test and migrate to latest SQL version.

Any suggestion to test this? Can we install VS 2005 on windows 2022 and try to open and make changes? (OR) install new SSDT for SQL 2022 and try it out?